# Как выбрать Э или Е после гласных?

Tags: графика

**Как делается выбор букв Э или Е после гласных** (в словарь не смотреть)? Можно ли выбрать Э/Е **по слуху**?

Слова с буквой Э: ***поэт, менуэт, силуэт, маэстро, каноэ.***

Слова с буквой Е: ***проект, проекция, пациент.***

Answer (score 2):

Вот что говорил Лопатин в своей статье (см. [здесь](http://gramota.ru/biblio/magazines/gramota/norma/28_367) на Грамота.ру) по поводу правописания новых слов в русском языке:

> Об отдельных словах. Одно дело формулировать правила для каких-то групп, типов слов, а другое — определять правильное написание отдельных конкретных новых слов, которые пишутся по-разному. Есть такое новое слово — **риелтор**. После и в нем пишут и **е** , и **э**, а после **т** — **о** или **е** — получается четыре возможных варианта написания. Какой из них выбрать? Мы предлагаем риелтор. Почему? **о** — потому, что так пишется в английском, надо учитывать написание слова в языке-источнике, а **е** после **и** — потому, что в других словах после **и** пишется не **э**, а **е**: сравните хотя бы слова *диета, диез, коэффициент, абитуриент, ингредиент, сиеста*. После **о** и **у** пишется **э**, а после **и** — **е**. Опираясь на это правило, можно смело рекомендовать написание **риелтор**.

Правда, в словах **проект** и **проекция** после **о** пишется **е**, но здесь, вероятно, сыграло свою роль латинское произношение слова (projectus — пройэктус).

Comment: Разочаровал меня Лопатин. По его "смелой" рекомендации мы должны  учитывать иностранную графику, оглядываться на традицию ранее заимствованных слов, а реальная русская фонетика как будто  ни при чем.   Ведь очевидно, что в словах проекция, пациент и всех прочих, где пишется Е, звук Э смягчается. Возьмите, к примеру,  слово "коэффициент", там в принципе возможны три произношения: твердый Э,  смягченный Э и йотированный ЙЭ. Как тут станешь грамотными с такими учителями, если все слова они предлагают заучивать наизусть  от сих и до сих. Так нельзя выбрать Э/Е по слуху, как Вы лично думаете?

Comment: @Jasmin Лопатин хочет лишь минимальным воздействием принести максимальную пользу. Я не вижу возможности выбирать по слуху, пока слово не закрепиться в языке. И я согласен с Лопатиным, что будет намного хуже, если разрешить все мыслимые варианты и ждать лет 50, какой из них победит в эволюционной борьбе.

Comment: Какая там эволюция! Буквенный состав слова однозначно определяется по словарю. Но  уже выбранная графика влияет на произношение, и пользователь может по слуху определить Э или Е пишется в конкретном слове. Что касается закономерностей, то важен тот факт, что после мягкого И согласный как правило смягчается и поэтому обозначается буквой Е. Такое полезное наблюдение, оно даже в учебниках  присутствует. Вот только составители забывают сказать, почему именно после И пишется Е (не знают или не хотят себя утруждать).

Comment: @Jasmin Похоже, я Вас не так понял. Но в любом случае, слух обманчив и не всегда подчиняется строгим правилам. Я в своём окружении всегда слышал "риЭлтор" и не помню, чтобы слышал иначе.

Comment: Это вообще интересное слово. Оно заимствовано из английского языка – realtor |rɪəltə| , и сначала там произносился звук Э. В словаре 2012 года приводятся два варианта записи: риэлтор и риелтор, потом оставляют один вариант: риелтор. Под него начинает подстраиваться и произношение, кроме того, сказывается влияние мягкого И. Я думаю, что в этом слове происходит постепенное смягчение Э, кстати ударного, ясно произносимого (в английском языке этот звук безударный). Если прислушаться, то это смягчение будет заметно, вряд ли кто сейчас произносить явно твердое Э, как в слове "этот",

Answer (score 2):

В целом, нельзя опираться на слух, надёжнее на *зрительную память*; в тяжёлых случаях может выручить словарь, но есть и простые формальные ориентиры, которыми можно пользоваться, ориентируясь на предполагаемый языковый источник заимствования.

Например, в правилах англо-русской практической транскрипции заимствуемых единиц (см. одноимённую вики-статью) есть такое обобщение, которому все приведённые примеры соответствуют: *после согласных и после "и"* (точнее, того, что передаётся этой русской буквой) исходное **e** передаётся как "**е**", *в остальных случаях* - как "**э**". В словах "**проект**", "**проекция**" в исходном варианте присутствует *согласный* j (в отличие от **поэт** и **каноэ**), но (в отличие от формы написания слова) произношение в заимствовании соответствует не английскому (прибл. "дж"), а латыни (йот), и отдельной буквой не передаётся, но ориентир на согласный звук перед проблемной буквой продолжает действовать.

Answer (score 0):

А я думаю, что этимология  вряд ли поможет нам выбрать нужную букву. Фонетика и графика языка-источника, безусловно, оказывают влияние на выбор Э/Е, но только **в начальный период.** Иногда наблюдаются колебания, сосуществование двух форм, но потом слово закрепляется в словаре в одном виде.

Написание уже давно заимствованных слов **можно определить по их звучанию**: обычно твердый звук Э  соответствует букве Э, а смягченный — букве Е.

Также дополнительно учитывается **предыдущая буква**: после У — ***менуэт, силуэт, статуэтка***, после И — ***пациент, аудиенция, реквием, иероглиф***. А вот для слове ***диета*** допускаются даже два варианта: мягкий Э и йотированный Э.

**Любопытна история слова** ***поэт***.

В начале XVIII века появились в русском языке слова ***поета*** (форма  на А) и ***поетика***. Потом ***поета*** превратилась в ***пииту***, и только в середине XVIII века появился наконец ***поэт*** (Державин любил употреблять эту форму), в словарях слово отмечено  в 1806 году. ***Поэт*** заимствован из французского языка (от ***poute***), но восходит к латинскому и греческому (от глагола делаю, совершаю, слагаю, воздвигаю).

**Проект.** Возникновение XVII — XVIII вв из немецкого языка,  восходит к латинскому ***projectum*** — смета, предложение (соответствующий латинский глагол имеет значение "держу впереди, вытягиваю, бросаю").

Comment: Думаю, этот момент надо подправить: _после У — менуэт, силуэт, **после И** — пациент, **траектория**._

Comment: Спасибо, исправлено.